# chromecast automation using selenium

Tags: selenium, chromecast

When trying to automate the chromecast using selenium, I am unable to find the cast icon on chrome.

Tried to add extension, created a default browser still no results.

Here is the code where I am trying to run using TestNG.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Selenium\\BrowserProfile");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://example.com");
```

Could you please let me know how we can automate the chromecast using selenium.

Comment: Um, it's not clear to me how your code is attempting to find the chromecast icon.  Where does your code fail?  What is the error message?

Comment: Chromecast icon is missing when chrome browser is opened with selenium webdriver. 

Cast icon is visible when I am opening chrome browser manually. But its missing when opened with selenium chrome webdriver with version 2.53 .

There are no errors in console though. Previously, cast_sender.js file was not getting loaded, but we added it manually by injecting it in script tag.Still the driver is unable to detect chromecast device.

Let me know if you have any other queries.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't have any experience with this but some things you could explore:  Perhaps there's a Capability or ChromeOption that will enable that chromecast icon, but I didn't find it with a quick search?  I've read of a chromedriver command line option --enable-video-player-chromecast-support .  I also notice that "Cast" is an option from the tools menu and from the right-click context menu, so perhaps you could find a way to access those controls instead of using the icon.